# Realm Database size

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have a model:

```
class PhoneExtModel: Object {
    dynamic var number: Int64 = 0 // setup Adding 81 before string
    dynamic var label = ""
    dynamic var isBlocked = false
    dynamic var groupId = 0
```

where 'number' is primary key.

When i add to realm base 7 000 000 entries, size of base file is 800 - 900 mb, is it normal ?

Answer (score 2):

While your app is running, Realm may need to store older versions of your data in addition to the latest version. For example, if you have `Realm` instances on side threads that point to older versions of your data and aren't refreshed, Realm needs to store both those older versions and the current version, and the file size will grow.

Depending on how you structure your write transactions to add those 7 million entries, your code may be holding on to multiple versions of the data simultaneously, which forces the Realm file to grow larger. We've seen this happen frequently, in particular, for users who use several worker threads to write to the database at the same time. You may want to make sure that your code does not keep multiple versions of the Realm open at the same time, and that once a `Realm` instance isn't useful anymore it is destroyed in a timely manner. (You may need to wrap it in an autorelease pool for this to happen.)

Once those old versions of the data stop being referenced, Realm knows that the space can be recycled and will reuse it in the future. You can also compact the file manually by writing a copy to it, and then replacing the original file with the copy.

You can read more about why Realm files sometimes grow larger than they should [in our documentation](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#file-size-and-tracking-of-intermediate-versions).